# VBA selecting range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I can set the range for all of a column such as :

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
```

But I'd like to set something such as

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A")
```

but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this or am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: I want to select a range of column A which begins at "A10" and does not end

Comment: What are you trying to do? How can you select from A:10 to the entire A column?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want. To select a complete column use `[A10].EntireColumn.Select`

Comment: I want to start at "A10" and continue to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a formula like A10:A you need to specify the last row if you don't want to select the whole column.

The first line in the code below will give you the number of rows in the sheet.  So the second line reads like ("A10:A1048576") unless you are using an older excel format.

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.rows.count
activesheet.range("A10:A" & lastRow)
```